# Read csv file from python

Tags: python, csv, xls

I had some data in excel file. I changed the file to .csv file and tried to write some python code to read the file.

But I am getting some unpredictable outputs.  My Code is like this:

```
INPUT_DIR = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"Input")
OUTPUT_DIR = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"Output")
print INPUT_DIR, OUTPUT_DIR 

def read_csv():    
    files = os.listdir(INPUT_DIR)
    for file in files:
        file_full_name = os.path.join(INPUT_DIR,file)
        print file_full_name
        f = open(file_full_name,'r')
        for line in f.readlines():
            print "Line: ", line

def create_sql_file():
    print "Hi"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    read_csv()
    create_sql_file()
```

This gives very peculiar output:

```
 C:\calcWorkspace\13.1.1.0\PythonTest\src\Input C:\calcWorkspace\13.1.1.0\PythonTest\src\Output
C:\calcWorkspace\13.1.1.0\PythonTest\src\Input\Country Risk System Priority Data_01232013 - Copy.csv
Line:  PK**
```

Does someone know of this issue?

Comment: Have you tried opening the file in a simple text editor, to verify its contents?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, make sure you converted the file from Excel to csv, using the `Save As` menu from Excel.  Simply changing the extension doesn't work.  The output you are seeing is data from Excel's native format.

Once you have converted the files, use the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html):

```
import csv

for filename in os.listdir(INPUT_DIR):
   with open(os.path.join(INPUT_DIR,filename), dialect='excel-tab') as infile:
      reader = csv.reader(infile)
      for row in reader:
          print row
```

If you want to read raw Excel files, use the [`xlrd` module](http://www.python-excel.org/). Here is a [sample](https://raw.github.com/python-excel/tutorial/master/students/xlrd/simple.py) that shows how to read Excel files.