# Reading file as array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a *cvs* file which has three columns of numbers up to three digits each:

```
1 0 0
2 0 0
3 0 0
4 0 0
5 0 0
6 0 0
7 0 0
8 0 0
9 0 0
10 0 0
11 0 0
```

I want to read the columns separately and be able to use them as arrays with:

```
data = np.loadtxt('file.csv')
x = data[:, 0]
y = data[:, 1]
```

But I'm getting:

```
X = np.array(X, dtype)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

If instead I use the line `x,y = np.loadtxt('Beamprofile.txt', usecols=(0,1), unpack=True)` the error disappears but *x* and *y* don't seem to be read correctly in further operations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read csv file from python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14725020/read-csv-file-from-python)

Comment: This is a numpy specific file read isue.

Comment: Show the shape and dtype of `data`.  Or even print a few rows of data or the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your sample:

```
In [1]: data=np.loadtxt('stack39174768.txt')
In [2]: data
Out[2]: 
array([[  1.,   0.,   0.],
       [  2.,   0.,   0.],
       [  3.,   0.,   0.],
       [  4.,   0.,   0.],
       [  5.,   0.,   0.],
       [  6.,   0.,   0.],
       [  7.,   0.,   0.],
       [  8.,   0.,   0.],
       [  9.,   0.,   0.],
       [ 10.,   0.,   0.],
       [ 11.,   0.,   0.]])
In [3]: x=data[:,0]
In [4]: y=data[:,1]
In [5]: x
Out[5]: array([  1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.,  10.,  11.])
In [6]: y
Out[6]: array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
```

Where's the problem?  Is there's something about the file that we're not seeing in the clip?

```
In [8]: x,y = np.loadtxt('stack39174768.txt', usecols=(0,1), unpack=True)
```

produces the same `x` and `y`.

I asked about shape and dtype

```
In [11]: data.shape
Out[11]: (11, 3)
In [12]: data.dtype
Out[12]: dtype('float64')
```

I like `np.genfromtxt` a little better, but in this case it produces the same `data`.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution to this could be to use pandas module in python, it gives the freedom to use column values as numpy array, which you can convert to list easily.

```
    import pandas as pd

    df = pd.read_csv(open("name_of_the_csv.csv"))
    # For one column, lets say the 1st one
    column_1_list = df[df.columns[0]].values
```

If you want to access all the columns you can use for loop and do it like shown below:

```
    df = pd.read_csv(open("name_of_the_csv.csv"))
    for i in xrange(len(df.columns)):
        column_list = df[df.columns[i]].values
```

Comment: For a file like that `numpy` is just a capable, and simple, as `pandas`.